# How can I show a parameter in sql string value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have can I execute below script in SQL

```
Select Year as ' years between ' +  @StartYear + '-' +  @EndYear + ' value ' 
from tblYears
where Year Between @StartYear and @EndYear
```

Comment: I believe `Have` is typo... It should be `How`. Isn't it?? Could you execute and see what error you are getting??

Comment: Should either be `[alias] = <expression>` or `<expression> AS [alias]`. Not sure where you got the `[alias] AS <expression>` syntax you're using.

Answer (score 3):

You have your `as` switched around.  The name comes last

```
Select 'years between ' +  @StartYear + '-' +  @EndYear + ' value ' AS Year
from tblYears
where Year Between @StartYear and @EndYear
```

Now @StartYear and @EndYear are probably not char/varchar/nchar/nvarchar so you will need to convert them.  I am going to assume here that your year is a 4 digit integer.  You will need to tweak this if it is not.

```
Select 'years between ' +  convert(char(4), @StartYear) + '-' +  convert(char(4), @EndYear) + ' value ' AS Year
from tblYears
where Year Between @StartYear and @EndYear
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is something like this, where you are inserting the selected row's value into the final output?

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(4), Year) + ' year is between ' 
    + CONVERT((CHAR(4),@StartYear) +'-'+ CONVERT((CHAR(4),@EndYear) + ' values.' 
FROM tblYears
WHERE Year BETWEEN @StartYear AND @EndYear
```

Otherwise, you do not even need the FROM or WHERE, as you will be printing the same thing over and over. Then, I would suggest:

```
SELECT ' years between ' + CONVERT((CHAR(4),@StartYear) + '-' 
    + CONVERT((CHAR(4),@EndYear) + ' value'
```